# shopware Controller does not get the template

Tags: php, smarty, shopware

i am trying to create a controller and show something on a view however it ooks like something is wrong. i created a plugin with the following files

SwagStartup/Controllers/Frontend/RoutingDemonstration.php

```
<?php
class Shopware_Controllers_Frontend_RoutingDemonstration extends Enlight_Controller_Action
{
    public function preDispatch(){
      $this->view->addTemplateDir(_DIR_.'/../../Resources/views');
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        //die('Hello world test !');
    }
}
```

SwagStartup/Resources/views/frontend/routing_demonstration/index.tpl

```
{extends file="parent:frontend/index/index.tpl"}

{block name="frontend_index_content"}
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
{/block}
```

i also have the config.xml,plugin.xml and 
SwagStartup.php in there right places.

when i uncomment the hello world i will see the text in the browser when i call the controller however when i comment it out then

```
Oops! An error has occurred!
We have been informed about the problem and try to solve it. Please try again within a short time.
```

so what could be the issue and am i missing anything?
i am using shopware version 5.4.6 
and [following this](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/controller/) did not help either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to update incase someone gets the same issue. my problem was here, i think its because i was tired i could not see it.

```
$this->view->addTemplateDir(_DIR_.'/../../Resources/views');
```

that should have been

```
$this->view->addTemplateDir(__DIR__.'/../../Resources/views');
```

it should be `__DIR__` and not `_DIR_`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add a detailed error message? The message "Oops!..." is only user output, not the technical error message.

https://en-community.shopware.com/Debugging-in-Shopware_detail_1912.html

I did the same in my testplugin: https://github.com/mnaczenski/ControllerTest/blob/master/Controllers/Frontend/Testcontroller.php

This works fine and renders the template of the plugin.

Comment: thank you so much for pointing that out i kept checking the log but nothing was there.